# MPI_Sendrecv with operation on recvbuf?

Tags: python, c, mpi, mpi4py

I use the `MPI_Sendrecv` MPI function to communicate arrays of data between processes. I do this in Python using mpi4py, but I'm pretty sure my question is independent of the language used.

What I really want is to add an array residing on another process to an existing local array. This should be done for all processes, so I use the `MPI_Sendrecv` function to send and receive the arrays in one go. I can then add the received array in the `recvbuf` to the local array and I'm done.

It would be nice however if I could save the step of having a separate `recvbuf` array, and simply receiving the data directly into the local array *without overwriting the existing data*, but rather updating it using some operation (addition in my case).

I guess what I'm looking for is a combined `MPI_Sendrecv`/`MPI_Reduce` function. Do some function like this exist in MPI?

Comment: Is this a pairwise operation - eg, every rank has some single neighbour this needs to happen on?  Can you tell us a bit more about the communications pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Recvreduce` is what you're looking for. Unfortunately, it doesn't exist yet. It's something that the MPI Forum has been looking at adding to a future version of the standard, but hasn't yet been adopted and won't be in the upcoming MPI 3.1.